# Помогите составить регэксп

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Впервые столкнулся с этой таинственной наукой составления регулярок.

Суть такова - нужно удалить все до второго пробела. Т. е. если дано

```
a b c
```

Нужно оставить только

```
c
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: язык\синтаксис какой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да в лоб, если нет других условий (если пробел - это не только пробел, и несколько считаются одним):

```
my $s = 'aa bb cc';
$s =~ s/^\S+\s+\S+(.*)$/$1/;
print "'$s'\n";
```

Вывод:

```
' cc'
```